# Servicestack - OR operator for consuming autoquery rdbms API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack, autoquery-servicestack

Is there a way to use OR operator for conditions in queries. I know that the modifier `[QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]` can be used but this will change the behavior of the property always. Maybe some times I need to query with AND and some times I need to query with OR, with the same field.
Something like

*state = la AND amount = 1000 OR totalamount=1000*

**become**

*{url}?state=la&amount=1000&**OR**totalamount=1000*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify an OR condition on the QueryString adhoc like this but you could potentially use a custom template to create a custom query, e.g:

```
public class Query : QueryDb<Table>
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "Amount = {Value} OR TotalAmount = {Value}")]
    public int AnyAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Which should let you then query with:

```
?anyamount=1000
```

Comment: is the QueryDbField still supported wit hservicestack 4.x?

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani this feature still exists and hasn't been removed.